# Node.js sync/async callback return a value from a database?

Tags: node.js, express

I apologise immensely for posting this question because I'm sure the answer is out there, but I'm simply unable to find the answer I'm looking for.

The question is, if you are making a HTTP request to a node.js server - how do you keep the connection open so that the database can return something?

Consider the following code;

```
app.get("/myRequest", function (req, response) {
  database.query('SELECT * FROM table', function(err, rows) {
    // Cannot return rows because the connection will have already been closed
    response.JSON(rows); // Doh!
  });
});
```

I suppose my question is, should I be tackling this by adapting the above example, or by editing the way the actual webserver is setup?

I'm using a simple httpserver, perhaps express.js would address this problem?

Comment: put the response as a callback to your query

Comment: What makes you think that the DB connection will have already been closed?

Answer (score 1):

When you write a route handler for node servers the connection does not close until you send a response. So if you wait to respond until after your database query returns the connection to the client will still be sitting there waiting for you to respond. The whole point of node is that it can handle many simultaneous connections in parallel instead of in series.

Comment: Thanks Daniel, so perhaps I simply need to pass the current scope through to the database query so that I can append a response there?

Comment: As Anders said, it should work as posted. As long as you create the function you're passing on the spot it will be part of a closure and will have access to response. If, on the other hand,  you define the function you're passing outside of the call to .get() then you'll need to pass response.